# Dynamodb scanning object attribute within an array

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How does one filter for nested attributes within an array? For example, with the schema below, how do I scan for locations with location_id of "xxxx"?

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "location_id": "xxxx",
            "location_name": "location x"
        },
        {
            "location_id": "yyyyy",
            "location_name": "location y"
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Dynamo does not support the conditional expression `contains()` where the path is nested within a set.

e.g. it would be able to support `contains(locations, xxxx)` if locations was not a set of maps, but cannot do `contains(locations.location_id, xxxx)` or `locations. contains(location_id, xxxx`).

In this case, however, you're using a Filter Expression, and it's important to understand that Filter Expressions are applied *after* the data has been taken from the table and you've been charged for taking that data. This means that the only real advantage to using them is that you transfer (typically for free) less data and get less data back in the client.

This means that for "complex" filters like you want, it's just as cost-efficient to filter the returned results yourself.